# Citrus framework: Type confusion in BeforeTest implementation

Tags: java, spring, citrus-framework

I took and adapted this example from the citrus documentation to create a before-test task.

```
public class BeforeTest extends TestRunnerBeforeTestSupport {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myCitrusJmsEndpointBeanId")
    private javax.jms.Queue injectedQueue;

    @Override
    public void beforeTest(TestRunner runner) {
        runner.purgeQueues(action -> action.queue(injectedQueue));
    }
}
```

When I start the test, Spring throws an Exception and compains that it cannot find a Bean of type `javax.jms.Queue`.

That's true, the bean id in the Qualifier is a Citrus JmsEndpoint that is created with

```
<citrus-jms:endpoint id="myCitrusJmsEndpointBeanId".../>
```

But it would be redundant to redefine the JmsEndpoint bean as Queue bean. On the other hand doesn't allow the Compiler to define the `injectedQueue` as JmsEndpoint.

Obviously I am doing something wrong here. Is there a complete example in the citrus samples? Or anywhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to define any `Queues` as Beans in you configuration you can do this.

```
public class PurgeQueuesBeforeSuite extends TestRunnerBeforeSuiteSupport {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("connectionFactory")
ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

@Override
public void beforeSuite(TestRunner runner) {
    runner.purgeQueues(action ->
    action.connectionFactory(queueConnectionFactory)
            .queue("QUEUE_NAME_1")
    .queue("QUEUE_NAME_2")
    .queue("QUEUE_NAME_3"));
  }
}
```

See the documentation [here](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#actions-purging-jms-destinations), the part with *Java DSL runner*.

**EDIT**

Here is a detailed description of the solution used by @burki.

Configure the queue names as properties in the **citrus.properties** file:

```
my.out.queue.name=MY_OUT_QUEUE
my.in.queue.name=MY_IN_QUEUE
```

You can then use them in the **citrus-context.xml** like this:

```
<citrus-jms:endpoint id="myOutQueueEndpoint"
                     destination-name="${my.out.queue.name}"
                     timeout="10000"/>
```

And in the **PurgeQueuesBeforeSuite** action like this:

```
public class PurgeQueuesBeforeSuite extends TestRunnerBeforeSuiteSupport {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("connectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

    @Value("${my.out.queue.name}")
    private String myOutQueueName;

    @Override
    public void beforeSuite(TestRunner runner) {
        runner.purgeQueues(action ->
        action.connectionFactory(queueConnectionFactory)
                .queue(myOutQueueName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and I thought this just creates the redundancy at another place: the queue names. But I can define them as properties and inject them with @Value